# How to mock HttpClient and HttpRequest for unit test in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, junit, httprequest, httpresponse

I have built a spring boot application that has a class called FileDetails.kt. The method that I am trying to test, in the class, is in the following format.

```
getFileDetails(auth: String, id: String): FileModel {
    val url = URI.create(“http://localhost:8080/$id”)
    val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build()
    val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(url).header(“Authorization”, auth).build()
    val response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
    return objectMapper.readValue(response.body(), object: TypeReference<FileModel>() {})}
```

I am writing a unit test to mock that when the response code is 200, we get a FileModel response. This is what I have done so far but unsure how to proceed.

```
@Test fun `test get file details method`() {
val response200 = Mockito.mock(HttpResponse::class.java)
val mockRequest = Mockito.mock(HttpRequest::class.java)
// not sure how to return mockRequest and response200}
```

I am fairly new this and would like to know if it is possible to mock these responses and how to go about that.

Answer (score 2):

You are going about this the wrong way.

If your aim is just to mock `getFileDetails()` then this is easy enough and you don't need to be bothered with `HttpResponse` at all.  Firstly, suppose your fetcher was in a class like this:

```
class Fetcher {

    fun getFileDetails(auth: String, id: String): FileModel {
        val url = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/$id")
        val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build()
        val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(url).header("Authorization", auth).build()
        return objectMapper.readValue(response.body(), object: TypeReference<FileModel>() {})}
    }

}
```

you simply write (and apologies I am using https://mockk.io/ not Mockito since Mockk is a mocking library specifically for Kotlin which I know better - but the concepts / approach is the same),

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk

val fetcher = mockk<Fetcher>()

every { fetcher.fetchRawResponse(any(), any()) } returns FileModel(...)
```

If you really wanted to test at a lower level with HttpRequest/Response, you will need to break down `getFileDetails` (Dependency Injection style).  What is it you are trying to test?

1. that the HTTP request is properly formed?
2. that the deserialization from String to `FileModel` is correct?

Suppose it was just (2) you wanted to test - I would keep away from testing any Http stuff and assume that the authors of HttpClient have tested their code properly, and abstract your external calls something like this:

```
class Fetcher {

    fun fetchRawResponse(auth: String, id: String) : HttpResponse<String> {
        val url = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/$id")
        val client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build()
        val request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(url).header("Authorization", auth).build()
        return client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
    }

}
```

Then the caller can do the `objectMapper.readValue` (or even go further and don't leak the `HttpResponse` object out of this method, by returning a plain `String`)

Supposing you had a `Fetcher` class like the above, this is how to use mock the response.

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.verify

    @Test fun `test get file details method`() {
        val jsonResponse: HttpResponse<String> = mockk()
        every { jsonResponse.body() } returns  """
            {"some":"json"}
        """.trimIndent()
        val fetcher = mockk<Fetcher>()
        every { fetcher.fetchRawResponse(any(), any()) } returns jsonResponse
        // now you can call fetcher.fetchRawResponse("abc","def")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the static mocking and capture capabilities of mockk to validate e.g. a POST request payload etc. along these lines:

```
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.mockkStatic
import io.mockk.slot
import java.net.http.HttpClient
import java.net.http.HttpRequest
import java.net.http.HttpRequest.BodyPublishers
import java.net.http.HttpResponse
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

    val httpClient = mockk<HttpClient>()
    val httpResponse = mockk<HttpResponse<String>>()

    every { httpResponse.body() } returns "ignored"
    every { httpResponse.statusCode() } returns 200

    val httpRequestCapturingSlot = slot<HttpRequest>()

    every {
        httpClient.send(
            capture(httpRequestCapturingSlot),
            HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()
        )
    } returns httpResponse

    val expectedRequestJson = Gson().toJson(
        <your expected payload object>
    )

    mockkStatic(BodyPublishers::class)
    val postBodyCapturingSlot = slot<String>()
    every { BodyPublishers.ofString(capture(postBodyCapturingSlot)) } returns BodyPublishers.ofString(
        "stand-in only",
        StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    )

    // make SUT call resulting in HttpRequest

    val contentHeader = "Content-Type" to listOf("application/json")

    val httpRequest = httpRequestCapturingSlot.captured

    httpRequest.method() shouldBe "POST"
    httpRequest.uri().toString() shouldBe <expected uri>
    httpRequest.headers().map() shouldContain contentHeader

    postBodyCapturingSlot.captured shouldBe expectedRequestJson
```